# End of first sequence of nans in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a two dimensional numpy array where some rows may have nans. I want to select the occurrence or absence of nans in rows of these arrays as per the following prescription:

- If a row does not start with a nan, then the result for that array will be -1.
- If a row starts with a nan, then the result will be the index of the last nan in the continuous unbroken sequence of nans which started at the beginning of that row.

**What is the most optimal way of doing this?** In my actual work, I will be dealing with numpy arrays with millions of rows.

As an example lets consider the below array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,11,np.nan,111,1111],
               [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 22],
               [np.nan, np.nan, 3, 33, np.nan],
               [4, np.nan, np.nan, 44, 444],
               [np.nan, 5, 55, np.nan, 555],
               [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])
```

Here the expected result will be `result = [-1, 2, 1, -1, 0, 4]`.

Below is a successful code that I have tried. But, I would like a more optimal solution.

```
result = []

for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    if np.isnan(arr[i])[0] == False:
        result += [-1]
    elif np.all(np.isnan(arr[i])):
        result += [arr.shape[1]-1]
    else:
        result += [np.where(np.isnan(arr[i]) == False)[0][0] - 1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a column of non-nan with [`hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), check which values are nan with [`isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) and get the position of the first non-nan with [`argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmin.html):

```
out = np.isnan(np.hstack([arr, np.ones((arr.shape[0], 1))])).argmin(axis=1)-1
```

Or without concatenation and using [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to fix the case in which [`all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html) values are nan:

```
tmp = np.isnan(arr)

out = np.where(tmp.all(axis=1), arr.shape[1], tmp.argmin(axis=1))-1
```

Output:

```
out = array([-1,  2,  1, -1,  0,  4])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr = np.array([[1, 11, np.nan, 111, 1111],
               [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 22],
               [np.nan, np.nan, 3, 33, np.nan],
               [4, np.nan, np.nan, 44, 444],
               [np.nan, 5, 55, np.nan, 555],
               [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)


res = (

np.where( np.isnan(arr[:,0]),  
    np.where(
        np.all(np.isnan(arr),axis=1),arr.shape[1] -1, # Condition 1
        np.argmax(~np.isnan(arr),axis=1) -1 # Condition 2
        )      
              
    ,-1)    
    
    
)

"""
print(res)
[-1  2  1 -1  0  4]
"""
```

EXPLANATION :

For the given array arr, the expected result is:

result = [-1, 2, 1, -1, 0, 4]

Row 0 doesn't start with a NaN, so its result is -1.
Row 1 starts with NaNs, and the last NaN in the initial sequence is at index 2.

Row 2 starts with NaNs, but the sequence breaks at index 2, so the result is 1.

Row 3 doesn't start with a NaN, so its result is -1.

Row 4 starts with a NaN, and that's the only NaN in the initial sequence, so the result is 0.

Row 5 is entirely NaNs, so the result is 4 (the index of the last NaN).

Condition 1 :

If the entire row consists of NaNs like this [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan] :

We code it in this way : np.all(np.nan(arr),axis=1)
Then we will consider the index of the last NaN in the array arr.
We code it in this way:  arr.shape[1] -1

We must put everything inside np.where() for that If condition.
Now, the full code becomes : np.where(np.all(np.nan(arr),axis=1),arr.shape[1] -1)

Condition 2 :
If the row consists of NaN and non-Nan values like this [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 22] :

Then We try to find the index of the first non-NaN value.
We code it in this way : np.argmax(~np.nan(arr),axis=1)
This will give 2 which is at index = 3
But We need the index of the last NaN before element 2.
That's why We will Subtract 1 from it.
Now, the full code becomes : np.argmax(~np.nan(arr),axis=1) -1

For that If condition, we will put the above code inside np.where().

Hence : np.where(np.argmax(~np.nan(arr),axis=1) -1)

Therefore We got 2 functions which can be put inside np.where()

Hence :

np.where(np.all(np.nan(arr),axis=1),arr.shape[1] -1,np.argmax(~np.nan(arr),axis=1) -1 )

Condition 3 :

If the row starts with a Nan or Not.

We code it in this way : np.isnan(arr[:0])
If not then we have to return -1
We code it in this way : np.where(np.isnan(arr[:, 0]), -1)

Final Structure :

np.where(Check 1st element is NaN, Check inner NaNs using Conditions 1 and 2 ,
return -1 if 1st element is not a NaN)

Now putting the codes together :

a = np.where(np.isnan(arr[:, 0]), -1)

b = np.where(np.all(np.nan(arr),axis=1),arr.shape[1] -1,np.argmax(~np.nan(arr),axis=1) -1 )

Final code :
res = np.where(np.isnan(arr[:, 0]),
np.where(np.all(np.nan(arr),axis=1),arr.shape[1] -1,
np.argmax(~np.nan(arr),axis=1) -1 ),
-1)